# Find expected retirement age of athletes in a certain sport given table of retirement probabilities

Tags: probability, expected-value

How would I find the **expected** retirement age of an athlete in a certain sport given a table of probabilities of retirement at working ages, i.e.:

| Age | Probability of retirement upon reaching said age |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 0% |
| 19 | .2% |
| ... |  |
| 49 | 87% |
| 50 | 100% |

I know that I can get the probability of retirement by a specific age j by using $1-\prod_{i=18}^{j} P'(i)$ where $P'(i)$ is function defined by the values in the table.

The expected value should be $\sum_{x=18}^{50} P(x)*x$ where $P(x)$ gives the ratio of those who retire at age x but I'm short of understanding how to derive this.

The source of the problem is a sports game I'm developing where players retire at the end of a season. I'm using a scaled exponential function to determine the values in the table. I'd like to tweak the function to achieve some realistic expected retirement age.

Comment: Doubtful that $87\%$ are retiring between their $49$th and $50$th birthdays.  Therefore, I infer that the table intends that $87\%$ retire before their $50$th birthday.  So, to compute what percentage of the people retire between their $49$th and $50$th birthdays, you would have to do $~\color{red}{\text{what} ~?}$

Comment: Column 2 is the probability that the athlete retires upon reaching the age in column 1. So, 87% is the probability that an athlete retires upon reaching 49 in the example table. * I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Does $49 | 87\%$ mean that 87% of people aged 49 or older are retired, or that if someone is 49 years old, there is a 87% probability that they will retire before they reach age 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table describes the conditional probability of retirement before the next birthday, given the athlete is still playing as of the age in the corresponding row.  For instance, given that an athlete is still playing upon reaching age $49$, the probability they will retire before reaching age $50$ is $0.87$.

In actuarial notation, if $x$ is the athlete's age in whole years, the second column gives the quantity $q_x$.

Since your table is large, I will make a simplified table with different probabilities to illustrate how the computation works.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & q_x & p_x = 1-q_x & k = x-18 &{}_{k} p_{18} & {}_{k|}q_{18} = (q_{x})({}_{k} p_{18}) & x ({}_{k|}q_{18}) \\
\hline
18 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0 & - & - & - \\
19 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 1 & 1.0000 & 0.1000 & 1.9000 \\
20 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 2 & 0.9000 & 0.1800 & 3.6000 \\
21 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 3 & 0.7200 & 0.2160 & 4.5360 \\
22 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 4 & 0.5040 & 0.2520 & 5.5440 \\
23 & 0.8 & 0.2 & 5 & 0.2520 & 0.2016 & 4.6368 \\
24 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 6 & 0.0504 & 0.0504 & 1.2096 \\
\hline
& & & & 3.4264 & 1.0000 & \color{red}{21.4264}
\end{array}$$

The columns have the following meanings:

1. $x$ is the athlete's age.
2. $q_x$ is the probability that the athlete will retire before their next birthday (i.e. before age $x+1$), given that they have not yet retired by age $x$.
3. $p_x$ is the probability that the athlete will continue playing until their next birthday, given they are currently playing at age $x$.
4. $k$ is the number of whole years the athlete has played since age $18$.
5. $_{k} p_{18}$ is the *cumulative* probability that an athlete who starts out at age $18$ remains active for another $k$ years.  The first row is not calculated for this entry because although the probability is $1$, it is not relevant to the result.  This value is calculated as the product of all of the values in the second column $p_x$ up to but not including the same row; e.g., ${}_3 p_{18} = (p_{18})(p_{19})(p_{20}) = (1.0)(0.9)(0.8) = 0.72$.
6. ${}_{k|}q_{18} = (q_x)(_k p_{18})$ is the probability that an athlete who starts out at age $18$ retires in the year they are age $x$--that is, they remain active for $k$ years and then retires in the following year.
7. $x({}_{k|}q_{18})$ is the weighted age at retirement at age $x$, where the weight is the probability of retirement at that age.

In this way, we can see that the sum of the probabilities in the sixth column must equal $1$, and the sum of the values in the final column is the expected age at retirement; in this example, $21.4264$.

However, you will also notice that the sum of the probabilities in the fifth column ${}_k p_{18}$, is exactly $18$ less than the sum of the final column.  This is not a coincidence:  the desired expected value can also be calculated as $$18 + \sum_{k \ge 1} {}_k p_{18}.$$  This allows us the convenience of not needing to calculate the last two columns.

For your purposes, you would construct a table in a similar fashion, with your own probabilities.

Comment: The actuarial notation is very helpful. Would $q_x$ be the same as force of mortality if this were framed as life expectancy?

Comment: @user3716957 Similar, but not quite.  The force of mortality is $\mu(x)$ or $\mu_x$.  In a sense, $q_x$ is like $\mu_x$ in that both are related to conditional failure, but the former is a one-year probability, whereas the latter is an instantaneous rate of failure and is expressed as a density.  Therefore, the force of mortality can exceed $1$, but $q_x$ cannot.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_of_mortality for more information.  For the model in your question, we would need additional information about the retirement rate for fractional ages to model $\mu_x$.